# Cannot get correct return message when consuming WCF web-service via NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, wcf

I have a WCF web-service. If I just put the URL into the browser, I will get the error message: Forbidden. But if I post data through Fetcher(a HTTP Simulator in OS X), I can get the correct return value.

Now, I tried to use NSURLConnection to post data to the web-service and fetch the return value.

```
    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:postURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", postData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLResponse * response = nil;
    NSError * error = [[NSError alloc] init];

    receivedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSString * receivedStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But all I get is just the html code of the error page I can see from the browser(that forbidden message).

Please help me figure it out. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I set up a PHP server and try to do the same thing. I works perfectly. Therefore, I highly doubt it is the WCF problem. Anyone has some good ideas?

Answer (score 0):

if you use generated .svc service you need to :

change

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

to

[request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

also you need to SOAPAction field according to operation you request

What is you postData?